# JRebel doesn't reload changes with Glassfish 3.1.2.1

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

I have a java EE 6 project with jax-rs and java 7 with glassfish 3.1.2.1 and Windows 10. I've install the jrebel plugin and I have enabled Jrebel in my project. This resulted in to create the api/src/main/resources/rebel.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  This is the JRebel configuration file. It maps the running application to your IDE workspace, enabling JRebel reloading for this project.
  Refer to https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/config.html for more information.
-->
<application generated-by="intellij" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://update.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/rebel-2_1.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="C:/MyProjects/api/target/classes">
        </dir>
    </classpath>

    <web>
        <link target="/">
            <dir name="C:/MyProjects/api/src/main/webapp">
            </dir>
        </link>
    </web>

</application>
```

In src/main/java/mypackage/myservice.java I have the following code:

```
@Path("/myendpoint")
@Stateless
public class MyClass{

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getByID(@PathParam("id")String id){


            JSONObject myObject= new JSONObject();
            myObject.put("name","Daniel Garcia Miguel");
            myObject.put("details","TOYOTA YARIS HYBRID - 2015 - ZXX2239");
            myObject.put("value","16.000,00€");
            myObject.put("status","suspended");
            myObject.put("test","ok");

            return Response.ok(myObject.toString(),MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();


    }
}
```

I start the debug mode with JRebel and as a start I can reach the endpoint I have created. I change then myObject.put("test","ok"); to myObject.put("test","ok3"); but nothing happens.

I have found the C:\Users\Auser.jrebel\jrebel.log and I can see some of the following:

```
2019-07-01 17:10:48.723 INFO  [45] [IntelliJFSNotify] Not watchable file CREATE C:\MyProjects\api\src\main\mypackage\myservice.java
```

Not sure if it means anything. I have tried to Build the project Build->Build Project and in the target I can see the myservice.class change. However I checked in glassfish and there is not such change occurred.

Any ideas what I should check further?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The log line you posted is for a .java file, so that should not cause any issues. :)
However, can you send your JRebel log files to **support@jrebel.com** or from IntelliJ: Help -> JRebel -> Submit a Support Ticket? The log files are located in your $USER_HOME/.jrebel folder.